# How would I be able to keep the other divs in my flexbox container stationary while increasing the font size of another?

Tags: html, css, position, font-size

I have two text `div` and a logo. Everything is inside a flexbox container. When I hover over my text I change the font size to be 30 from 24 for a nice effect but because the content is spaced evenly in my div it effects the other `div` in the flexbox.

Here is a short GIF of what currently happens:
[image]

The reason why I am still using flexbox is because I still want the navigation bar to adapt to window size changes and this is the easiest way I know of accomplishing that. Is there anyway to fix this so that the text size increase does not affect the other `div` without losing the responsive nature of flexbox?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'epic pixel font'
}

body {
  margin-top: 110px;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  transition: height 200ms ease;
  font-family: 'Epic Pixel Font';
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar:hover {
  height: 150px;
}

.logo {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar-text {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar-text a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: 100ms ease;
}

.index-navbar-text a:hover {
  color: #0d1321;
  font-size: 32px;
  ;
}
```

```html
<body class="index-body">
  <nav class="index-navbar navbar">
    <div class="index-navbar-text navbar-text">
      <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <div>
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="images/LogoBlue.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="index-navbar-text navbar-text">
      <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: You can set a proper width to the first div with 'PROJECTS', which can contain the 'PROJECTS' of 32px.

Answer (score 1):

CSS transform scale can help here. While the scaled element changes in size it is considered still to occupy its original space.

This snippet scales the anchor element's parent div when hovered as well as changing the anchor's color.

```html
<style>
  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'epic pixel font'
  }
  
  body {
    margin-top: 110px;
  }
  
  .navbar {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    transition: height 200ms ease;
    font-family: 'Epic Pixel Font';
    user-select: none;
    z-index: 1;
    /* ADDED TO MAKE THE WHITE TEXT VISIBLE */
    background: #bbbbbb;
    ;
  }
  
  .navbar:hover {
    height: 150px;
  }
  
  .logo {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
  
  .navbar-text {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 100ms ease;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  .navbar-text a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: 100ms ease;
  }
  
  .navbar-text:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3333);
  }
  
  .navbar-text:hover a {
    color: #0d1321;
    /*font-size: 32px;;*/
  }
</style>

<body class="index-body">
  <nav class="index-navbar navbar">
    <div class="index-navbar-text navbar-text">
      <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <div>
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="images/LogoBlue.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="index-navbar-text navbar-text">
      <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```